# How to find the file path of a directory from the directory name alone?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that is supposed to take input from the user a directory name somewhere on the file system. Now, I have to take that directory name and translate it to a file path so that I may list the name of the files within it and their file paths.

```
import os
filepath = input("Please enter a directory: ")
print('\nFile Name: ' + os.path.basename(filepath))
print('File Path: ' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(filepath)), sep='\n')
```

So far, I've been able to get the file name and other information by inputting the whole file path, but that's not what I need. Just the directory holding files.

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot find a directory or file by its name if the name is not in the `sys.path` list.

If you have to find a directory of the name in somewhere else, you can:

```
import os
import pathlib

for d in pathlib.Path('/SOMEWHERE/ELSE').rglob('DIRECTORY_NAME'):
    # check if a directory
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        ...
```

You may set `/SOMEWHERE/ELSE` a directory `/`. In this case, be careful with permissions.